# Add element to control template in code

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

Let's say I have a common `UserControl` that has it's default `ControlTemplate`. Now I want to add an `AdornerDecorator` as the root element of the `ControlTemplate`.

How would I do that?

My attempt so far is the following:

```
UserControl view;
var templateWithAdornerDecorator = new ControlTemplate(view.GetType());
var adornerDecorator = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(AdornerDecorator));
var otherView = new FrameworkElementFactory(view.GetType());
otherView.SetValue(Control.TemplateProperty, view.Template);
adornerDecorator.AppendChild(otherView);
templateWithAdornerDecorator.VisualTree = adornerDecorator;
view.Template = templateWithAdornerDecorator;
```

(My `view` might be of a derived type of `UserControl`.)
But that crashes with a StackOverflowException :(

**EDIT:**
`MyUserControl` has this xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.Wpf.Sample.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    ABA
</UserControl>
```

and this is the xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the template. You could clone the existing template using the `XamlWriter`/`XamlReader` classes.

Try this:

```
MyUserControl view = new MyUserControl();
string xaml;
ControlTemplate ct = view.Template;
using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(ct, stream);
    xaml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}

XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";
XDocument oldTemplateXml = XDocument.Parse(xaml);
XElement newTemplateXml = new XElement(ns + "ControlTemplate",
new XElement(ns + "AdornerDecorator", oldTemplateXml.Root.DescendantNodes().First()));

ControlTemplate newTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(newTemplateXml.ToString()) as ControlTemplate;
view.Template = newTemplate;
```

Comment: Could you please try this code, with `MyUserControl` being a derived class from `UserControl` with its own xaml. I get an `System.Xml.XmlException` with message like **The ':' char, hexadecimal value 0x3A, must not be contained**.

Comment: Please post the complete XAML markup of the UserControl then.

Comment: The sample markup you have provided is invalid but if your put "ABA" in a TextBlock my sample code works.

Comment: Why is the markup invalid? I can set the `Content`-property to any instance of `object`. But nevertheless, I get the same System.Xml.XmlException when I put the `TextBlock` in there. I am on *.NET 4.5* and *C# 5*

Comment: Please upload a repo if your issue somewhere then. It is impossible to tell what you are doing wrong based on the information you have provided. It clearly works for me.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample wpf application to: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoFjh2NQBk3Ci9p26PYf1Jo4JiruGQ

Comment: As I wrote in my answer the namespace should be defined as an XNamespace and not as a const string: XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation". Change this and your example works.